# Show that $ \left \| p \right \|=\left \| b \right \|\cos \theta$ from $p=\hat{x}a = \frac{a^{T}b}{a^{T}a}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Since $\left||a\right\|^{2} =  a^{T}a$ and $a^{T}b = \cos \theta \left ||a\right|\left||b\right|$, then $p=\hat{x}a = \frac{\cos \theta \left ||a\right|\left||b\right|}{\left||a\right\|^{2}}a$. I cancel out the $\left||a\right||$ and $p=\hat{x}a = \frac{\cos \theta\left||b\right||}{\left||a\right\|}a$

$\left|| p \right|| =\cos \theta\left||b\right||$

Is this correct? In the last step I took the length of $\left||b\right||$ and I assumed that it's still $\left||b\right||$. So I'm a little iffy on that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite correct transformation.

$\frac{\cos \theta ||b||}{||a||}$ is a scalar, and according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space out from the norm sign it must be carried out with modulus sign.

$||p|| = \left|\left| \frac{\cos \theta ||b||}{||a||}a \right|\right| = \left|\frac{\cos \theta ||b||}{||a||}\right|||a|| = |\cos \theta|\cdot||b||$